# Pyspark from_unixtime (unix_timestamp) does not convert to timestamp

Tags: date, pyspark

I am using Pyspark with Python 2.7. I have a date column in string (with ms) and would like to convert to timestamp

This is what I have tried so far

```py
df = df.withColumn('end_time', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(df.end_time, '%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S.%f')) )
```

`printSchema()` shows
`end_time: string (nullable = true)`

when I expended timestamp as the type of variable

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with some small sample inputs and the desired output. [How to create good reproducible spark examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`from_utc_timestamp`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_utc_timestamp

df = df.withColumn('end_time', from_utc_timestamp(df.end_time, 'PST'))
```

You'd need to specify a timezone for the function, in this case I chose `PST`

If this does not work please give us an example of a few rows showing `df.end_time`

Comment: Thank you, this worked, also preserved the milliseconds!

Comment: Hi Tanjin, I came across the same the problem. I tried your method, it went through and I did get a new column 'start_date' in timestamp format, but the values all are null. Can you help to take a look?

df1= df1.withColumn('start_date', f.from_utc_timestamp(df1.start_time, 'PST'))
df1.printSchema()
df1.select('start_time', 'start_date').show(5)

root
 |-- start_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_date: timestamp (nullable = true)

+-------------+----------+
|   start_time|start_date|
+-------------+----------+
|1597670747141|      null|
|1597664804901|      null|

Answer (score 7):

Create a sample dataframe with Time-stamp formatted as string:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC', ),('23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC',)], ['TIME'])
df.show(2,False)
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
|TIME                        |
+----------------------------+
|22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC|
|23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC|
+----------------------------+
root
|-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
```

Converting **string time-format** (including milliseconds ) to **unix_timestamp(double)**. **Since unix_timestamp() function excludes milliseconds we need to add it using another simple hack to include milliseconds.** Extracting milliseconds from string using substring method (start_position = -7, length_of_substring=3) and Adding milliseconds seperately to unix_timestamp. (Cast  to substring to float for adding)

```py
df1 = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp",F.unix_timestamp(df.TIME,'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z') + F.substring(df.TIME,-7,3).cast('float')/1000)
```

Converting **unix_timestamp(double)** to **timestamp datatype** in Spark.

```py
df2 = df1.withColumn("TimestampType",F.to_timestamp(df1["unix_timestamp"]))
df2.show(n=2,truncate=False)
```

This will give you following output

```
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|TIME                        |unix_timestamp  |TimestampType          |
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|22-Jul-2018 04:21:18.792 UTC|1.532233278792E9|2018-07-22 04:21:18.792|
|23-Jul-2018 04:21:25.888 UTC|1.532319685888E9|2018-07-23 04:21:25.888|
+----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Checking the Schema:

```
df2.printSchema()


root
 |-- TIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unix_timestamp: double (nullable = true)
 |-- TimestampType: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 4):

in current version of spark , we do not have to do much with respect to timestamp conversion.

using to_timestamp function works pretty well in this case. only thing we need to take care is input the format of timestamp according to the original column.
in my case it was in format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.
other format can be like MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss or a combination as such.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
df=df.withColumn('date_time',to_timestamp('event_time','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
df.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Following might help:-

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn("end_time", F.from_unixtime(F.col("end_time"), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS').cast("timestamp"))
```

[Updated]

Comment: `func.col` is not defined.

Comment: `df = SparkSQLContext.createDataFrame([("2018-02-11 04:21:25.12", ), ("2018-02-12 04:22:26.13", )], ["end_time"])`   Does not work on this dataframe, Gives null values in end_time column

Comment: Wed Oct 19 00:15:13 EST 2022 I'm trying to convert this to timestamp. I tried all the above logics, but getting some time difference from actual time. Any help would be appreciated.