# Convert Unix Timestamp into ms timestamp in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a column in my Dataframe *timestamp*, which contains UNIX 13-digit timestamps as follows:

```
|   timestamp   | 
| ------------- |
| 1584528257638 |
| 1586618807677 |
| 1585923477767 |
| 1583314882085 |
```

With pandas it is fairly easy to convert it like:

```
ms = pd.to_datetime(df[column], unit='ms')
df[column] = ms
```

However, in pySpark it is not that easy and I found some others, such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337991/pyspark-from-unixtime-unix-timestamp-does-not-convert-to-timestamp) trying to achieve this goal. 
The concatenation of the last Milliseconds does not work for me, it always results in the Second timestamp (HH:mm:ss) instead of HH:mm:ss.SSS.

What I tried so far was:

```
df = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp", F.unix_timestamp(df.timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z') + F.substring(df.timestamp, -3,3).cast('float')/1000)

df = df.withColumn("ms_Timestamp", F.to_timestamp(df["unix_timestamp"]))
```

This unfortunately, didn't convert it into a millisecond timestamp and I have no idea what else to do.

I would appreciate any help to finally get a millisecond timestamp.

All the best and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try usng `df = df.withColumn("timestamp",  F.to_timestamp(F.col("timestamp")))`?

Comment: That is unfortunately not working for me. Results in the normal seconds timestamp and discards the milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default **`to_timestamp, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp`** functions will not result milliseconds.

But to get workaround use **`from_unixtime`** and **`concat`** functions to get the timestamp with millisecs.

```
#using substring function
df.withColumn("unix_timestamp", concat_ws(".",from_unixtime(substring(col("timestamp"),0,10),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),substring(col("timestamp"),-3,3))).show(10,False)

#using divide function
df.withColumn("unix_timestamp", concat_ws(".",from_unixtime((col("timestamp")/1000),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),substring(col("timestamp"),-3,3))).show(10,False)
#+-------------+-----------------------+
#|timestamp    |unix_timestamp         |
#+-------------+-----------------------+
#|1584528257638|2020-03-18 05:44:17.638|
#|1586618807677|2020-04-11 10:26:47.677|
#|1585923477767|2020-04-03 09:17:57.767|
#|1583314882085|2020-03-04 03:41:22.085|
#+-------------+-----------------------+
```